# Compiler error on including a file that it is there

Tags: c++, c++17, assimp, premake

I'm having an issue trying to make Assimp work in an engine I'm doing. I'm trying to add it as a submodule and build it with premake, and I managed to properly include it as a project in the solution, but I'm having an error that I cannot understand.

The error is that some files in assimp are giving me a "cannot include file" error, which is weird because the file it is there, the next image shows it:

[image]

I checked the working directory of the project and it is in 'vendor/Assimp' (check the image), so it should be able to include the file. I'm assuming it must be something on the include directories, but I can't manage to find specifically what it is... Does somebody have any clue? Thanks!

The specific errors I'm having in this case is the next:

```
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "contrib/zip/src/zip.h" Assimp  C:\Users\lucho.suaya\Documents\GitHub\Kaimos\KaimosEngine\vendor\Assimp\code\3MF\D3MFExporter.cpp   61

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'contrib/zip/src/zip.h': No such file or directory    Assimp  C:\Users\lucho.suaya\Documents\GitHub\Kaimos\KaimosEngine\vendor\Assimp\code\3MF\D3MFExporter.cpp   61
```

And the include directories I'm adding in the premake file of the Assimp project are the next ones:

```
includedirs
    {
        "include",
        "code",
        "code/Common",
        "code/PostProcessing",
        "code/AssetLib",
        "contrib/irrXML",
        "contrib/rapidjson/include",
        "contrib/unzip"
    }
```

Then I have another premake file for the engine project in which i wrote the next (regarding assimp):

```
IncludeDir["Assimp"] = "%{wks.location}/KaimosEngine/vendor/Assimp/include"
include "KaimosEngine/vendor/Assimp"   -- Includes Assimp Premake File

includedirs { "%{IncludeDir.Assimp}" }
links { "Assimp" }
```

Comment: Please post all code and errors as text. To include that file the path to `Assimp` needs in be in the list of include directories.

Comment: none of the two folders that you are showing are in the includedirs list.

Comment: I posted the errors I have for this case, then I have a couple more files in which happens exactly the same @RichardCritten

Comment: Also forgot to say, I have a premake file for the engine in which the path to assimp is included (otherwise it wouldn't create the project for Assimp and it wouldn't try to compile it), I'm gonna add that now... But with that, it shouldn't be necessary to add anything in the Assimp premake includes, since its root is 'Assimp/' and it should be able to access, from there, to the files it wants to access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by including **in the project** many files I didn't include